# fortify data from shp file and promote it to SpatialPixelsDataFrame

Tags: r, ggplot2, raster, shapefile

I am trying to fortify a large shp file to raster file for analyzing (‘Koeppen Geiger’ climatic zones) with several locations. I got an error message running the ggplot and final line of code:

> Error in points2grid(points, tolerance, round) :    dimension 1 :
>   coordinate intervals are not constant

```
library(raster)
library(sp)
library(maptools)
library(rgdal)
library(ggplot2)
library(rgeos)

##reading shp file [https://www.climond.org/Core/Authenticated/KoppenGeiger.aspx][1]
shape.dir <- "WC05_1975H_Koppen_Shapefile"
lon.shape <- readOGR(shape.dir, layer = "WC05_1975H_Koppen")
##fortify the data
lon.df <- fortify(lon.shape, region = "Koppen")
##Using ggplot2 and get the wrong color zones
map <- get_map(location = c(73.60226,  15.77538, 153.9856, 53.56944),
               color = "color",source = "google",
               maptype = "terrain")
ggmap(map) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x = long,
                   y = lat,
                   fill = id),
               data = lon.df) +
  labs(x = "Longitude",
       y = "Latitude")
## The color presented was wrong with ‘Koeppen Geiger’ climatic zones
#convert to sp SpatialPointsDataFrame
coordinates(lon.df) = c("long", "lat")
#promote to SpatialPixelsDataFrame
gridded(lon.df) <- TRUE
```

Comment: without having access to the data it's hard to test your code.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, I attached the link that is available: https://docs.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=0B4vIx9MCfJgfOGRWcEhrU0duWGc&export=download

Comment: have you seen this thread http://r-sig-geo.2731867.n2.nabble.com/problem-with-gridded-td5817220.html

Comment: Yes, I tried the approaches suggested by Pierre. However, the problems keeps pup out. Should I try to generate a prediction 
grid through spsample function?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps do

```
x <- lon.shape
gridded(x) <- TRUE
```

Comment: I got the following Error message,Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘gridded<-’ for signature ‘"SpatialPolygonsDataFrame", "logical"’

Comment: All right, so you have polygons that you want to rasterize? If so, see `raster::rasterize`. It is rather unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I thought there are some issues while reading .shp file at the first. I am trying to rasterize my file and will try to find another .shp file. Thank a lot for your answer.